# Update all PostgreSQL databases without losing data

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am a novice web application developer and I am learning by developing a web app where each successfully registered user will login to his database. all the users have **the same database schema** and there comes a time where I need to update the schema because of a feature I've added.

I am trying to find away to update all the databases (PostgreSQL) with a new schema in one single command in the Package Manager Console of Visual Studio.

My normal approach is that I create a migration (my new schema) with the following command:

> add-migration -context MyContextRecords initial

then the next command which I do is:

> update-database -context MyContextRecords

The second command works with one database at a time that I specify in my class and I have to drop and delete the database before typing this command, doing so means that all data is lost that the user stored. not to mention if I have 100 of users.... doing this command one at time for each registered user isn't convenient at all... so I am sure there must be a better way?!?!?

So, is there a better approach in the Package Manager Console to be able to update all the databases schema for all the users, without Drop/Delete (pgAdmin) and lose data.

Thanks :)

Comment: why are you using a separate database for each user?

Comment: But.. the database migrations can be triggered in code; all those console commands are doing is adding the code files for you and snapshotting the db. You can choose when and what db to apply the migrations to, though granted it's a bit awkward if you have a hundred db and a hundred connection strings and hence need to cycle through a hundred contexts. Like Garr said, wouldn't it just be easier to have a db for everyone? If your users demand data separation and their own service that's ok; you'll have a hundred servers and a hundred config files with one constr each.Deploy to all,migrate works

Comment: I got the impression from your Q that you have one server with 100 db- that's more a nuisance

Comment: Yes I have one Server, where there can be as much databases as possible and like I said, I am just learning more about it and experimenting. I was thinking of keeping the migration from now on and instead of creating a new one, I would simply modify it by adding the new columns I want. and write some sort've script that updates all the database that exists with this modified migration. would that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. You can update your database without deleting or dropping your it in PG-ADMIN as long as you keep your initial migration files and never delete them. It was a mistake that I was doing by deleting them and creating a new migration.The right way to do things is to keep your first migrations files which include the ContextModelSnapshot.cs. From there you simply need to create a new migration. Updating will now work and you won't lose any data.

As for updating all the database in one single shot is discussed at this link:
[How to use the optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql with multiple connection strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398191/how-to-use-the-optionsbuilder-usenpgsql-with-multiple-connection-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on [Database versioning](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/database-versioning-best-practices/).

The short of it is that the database should know what version it is in. You can then run a series of sql scripts to update the database from that version to the latest one. This should keep existing data if possible, but it might need to handle missing data, or changes to the structure of data.

There are also database tools that can take two database schemas and create update scripts for them. But that might be error prone if there are large changes.

In either case you probably want to script the update. I.e. take the site offline, take a backup, run your script, update the website and bring everything online again. Make sure to test your update script on a test system with backup copies of the databases before doing it for real. Since it is scripted it would not matter if there are one or hundreds of databases, other than time at least.

This is a somewhat complicated problem, so I would not expect any trivial one button solutions to it.